# What OSes don't yet have Bitcoin clients?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Bitcoin has clients created for many OSes already, but which (semi-)significant operating systems don't yet have a Bitcoin client created for them?

Is there some opensource code I can use as a template to create a Bitcoin client for an OS that doesn't yet have a client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bitcoin [source](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) is free derive and redistribute. I believe some microarchetectures (some flavors of ARM?) are currently unsupported.